# How to change a theme's settings in Visual Studio Code

Tags: themes, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to follow the [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes) on Visual Studio's website, but I keep getting an error, take a look at the image below.

[image: Error]

The specific theme's color changes, but when I try to switch to another theme this error appears (the `default settings` on the left cannot be overwritten).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VSCode settings is a JSON file, that mean that after each key-value pair you need a comma `,`

So the line above the one with the error should look like:

```
"workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro",
```

Hope that solves your issue!

Comment: Damn, such a rookie mistake. I had tried many things before arriving at the image I posted here, the comma was then forgotten. Thank you.